# Get python cpu usage

Tags: windows, monitoring, python, central-processing-unit

Anyone using a Python script to monitor CPU usage on a Windows machine ? i've google for some time but have not been able to find any usable script. could you guys show me some example of what you're using ?

Here is the errors i got.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in 
    import wmi
  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 141, in 
    from win32com.client import GetObject, Dispatch
ImportError: No module named win32com.client
```

Comment: Did you install pywin32?

Comment: howdy, i installed win32 on another machine and it works like a charm. for my developing app i decided to use perl instead, since the ActivePerl package installer is very easy to use, and permits me to search and add what pachets i do need

Answer (score 2):

Us psutil module, it provides for memory, cpu, netowrk, etc usages. Visit their project webpage http://code.google.com/p/psutil/ .

Answer (score 1):

Lucky ol' you gets to dig around in WMI. Check out the [Python module 'wmi'](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi.html) which is about as good as I've seen.

Comment: i tried that one, i just wasn't able to get that module installed, and i thought there was some other way to achieve this task.

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: i updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the python win32 extensions which you can find [here](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html).

Answer (score 0):

[This blog entry](http://codepoetry.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/get-windows-cpu-usage-with-python/) shows some code:

```
def get_cpu_load():
    """ Returns a list CPU Loads"""
    result = []
    cmd = "WMIC CPU GET LoadPercentage "
    response = os.popen(cmd + ' 2>&1','r').read().strip().split("\r\n")
    for load in response[1:]:
       result.append(int(load))
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_cpu_load()
```